# R Markdown: add a frame to an inserted figure

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I am writing a report.pdf in R Markdown and want to include a pdf as a figure.
The chunk looks like this:

```
include_graphics("path/to/figure.pdf")
```

The chunk works fine, but since the figure has a white margin, it is not clear on the output page where the figure starts/ends. Therefore, I would like to add a simple frame around the figure.
Does `knitr` provide that option?

I've looked for similar questions on rseek.org, scanned through Yihui's book on bookdown and searched the `knitr` package documentation without finding anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349918/image-frame-borders-in-pdf-from-latex-template-with-pandoc-markdown):

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes: |
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
    \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}} 
---


```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("images/example.pdf")
```
````

**Result**:

[image]